# find flow of vector field $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\sin(y^{2}z^{2})\vec{i}+(2-xy)\vec{j}+z^{2}\vec{k}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, differential-forms

Quarter of a Sphere S given by the equation :

$ x^{2}+y^{2}+z^{2} = 16 \; \; $ with  $, \; \; y\geq 0 \; \; ,\; \; z\geq 0$
 oriented to the point $(0,2\sqrt{2},2\sqrt{2})$ with a normal vector $\vec{n}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\vec{j}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\vec{k}$

How can we calculate the flow of the vector field :

$\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\sin(y^{2}z^{2})\vec{i}+(2-xy)\vec{j}+z^{2}\vec{k}$

Comment: If you put a differential-forms tag, you should expect a solution using differential forms. Multivariable calculus is the appropriate tag, I think. There's no differential geometry here, either. Anyhow, you are asking for the *flux*, not the *flow*, of the vector field. Please show your work and show where you got stuck. You should have a formula to work with.

Comment: Hello Ted , you're right I used the given formula for the flux and got my result , I'll post it tonight with latex so everyone can see. Sorry for the mistake , yes I meant flux , I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: I understand the language issue. And it's great that you now have it figured out! Well done! (The flow of a vector field is a very different creature.)